# Не срабатывает opacity при наведении

Tags: css, вёрстка, opacity

При наведении на картинку появляется блок `.hid`, далее при наведении на `hid`, нужно чтобы срабатывал `opacity`, но ничего не происходит. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема?

```
.hid {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: #2E2E2E;
  padding:0.6em;
  left: 35%;
  top: 60%;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: medium;
}
.hid:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: white;
}
.cart:hover .hid{
    opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transition: all.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:     all.5s ease;
    -o-transition:       all.5s ease;
    transition:          all.5s ease;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения вашей проблемы необходимо в `.hid:hover` для `opacity: 0.5;` задать `!important`
CSS код:

```
.hid {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: #2E2E2E;
    padding:0.6em;
    left: 35%;
    top: 60%;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: medium;
}

.cart:hover .hid{
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:     all.5s ease;
    -o-transition:       all.5s ease;
    transition:          all.5s ease;
}

.hid:hover{
    opacity: .5 !important;
    color: white;
}
```

В ваших стилях поставьте `.hid:hover{}` после `.cart:hover .hid{}`

Comment: спасибо, !important помог

Answer (score 5):

Ответ в вашем же коде:

```
.hid:hover {
    opacity: 0.5; /* Тут */
    color: white;
}
.cart:hover .hid {
    opacity: 1; /* И вот тут */
     -webkit-transition: all.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:     all.5s ease;
    -o-transition:       all.5s ease;
    transition:          all.5s ease;
}
```

Думаю Ваш блок выглядит примерно так:

```
<div class="cart">
    <div class="hid">
        <!-- *** -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Тут получается так, что при наведение на `hid` вы наводите и на `cart` => получается что `hid` применит последний ховер эффект, которым является `.cart:hover .hid`, где `opacity: 1;`.

---

HTML код ничего не дал.. Вариантов может быть много, прям с ходу только два:

**1 вариант**

```css
body {
  font-size: 0;
}

.cart {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
  background: #999;
}

.cart .hid {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 25px;
  background: #333;
}

.cart:hover .hid {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart">
  <div class="hid"></div>
</div>

<div class="cart">
  <div class="hid"></div>
</div>

<div class="cart">
  <div class="hid"></div>
</div>

<div class="cart">
  <div class="hid"></div>
</div>

<div class="cart">
  <div class="hid"></div>
</div>

<div class="cart">
  <div class="hid"></div>
</div>
```

**2 вариант**

```css
body {
  font-size: 0;
}

.cart {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
  background: #999;
}

.cart .hid {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 25px;
  background: #333;
}

.carts:hover .cart:not(:hover) {
  opacity: .25;
}

.cart:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.cart:hover .hid {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="carts">
  <div class="cart">
    <div class="hid"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cart">
    <div class="hid"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cart">
    <div class="hid"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cart">
    <div class="hid"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cart">
    <div class="hid"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cart">
    <div class="hid"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cart">
    <div class="hid"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cart">
    <div class="hid"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а можно что то сделать, чтобы добиться желаемого результата, работая только с этими классами?

Comment: Смотря что вы хотите сделать. Чем больше кода предоставите по данным элементам, тем быстрее и точнее будет решён ваш вопрос.

Comment: Мне нужно,что бы при наведении на hid работал opacity, html код я дополнил

Comment: @КириллЧетвертков, дополнил ответ